# CoreText: How to keep a fixed line height and baseline when using different fonts of same point size in one line?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, core-text, typography

I'm implementing a custom rich text editor, most part of it works fine, it uses core text to layout and display text.

But I've run across a problem, when I have a line of text that contains different fonts of the same point size ,for example, Helvetica size 17 and STHeitiSC-Light size 17, the line height will be taller than lines containing only STHeitiSC-Light,size 17.

I found that the descender of Helvetica is bigger than that of STHeitiSC-Light ,

- when there are both Helvetica and STHeitiSC-Light, line ascender,descender,leading are A/D/L = 14.62/3.90967/0.51,
- when there is only STHeitiSC-Light, it's  A/D/L = 14.62/2.38/0.51.

Also, when there are only STHeitiSC-Light text in the line, then add a Helvetica character, the base line of those STHeitiSC-Light text will be moved(because the baseline of this line is changed), making a bad user experience.

So, how to keep a fixed line height and baseline when using different fonts of same point size in one line?
cou